# How to callback custom field text

Tags: php, metabox, query

I have a plugin where the user can click a button to feature a post.

I added a text field but i want the text field to call back whatever is posted in it

Here is how it looks now

http://ratedrnb.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/ffm2.jpg

now  the plugin grabs the thumbnail of the post but  i also want it to grab whatever is in the "Artist/Song" field.

Here is the code where the "Featured Music Options" is

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Featured Music
Plugin URI: LittleLadyEnterprises.com
Description: This Plugin is used to show your featured Posts/Pages with thumbnails in a nice slider.
Version: 2.6
Author: Little Lady Enterprises
*/

  $m_slider_options_page = get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-admin/admin.php?page=rated-featured-music/options.php';

 function m_slider_options_page() {

add_options_page('Featured Music Options', 'Featured Music', 10, 'rated-featured-music/options.php');

 }

 add_action('admin_menu', 'm_slider_options_page');

 function m_slider_add_scripts() {

    if ( !is_admin() ) {

            wp_register_script('jquery.cycle', get_bloginfo('url') . '/wp-content/plugins/rated-featured-music/scripts/jquery.cycle.all.2.72.js', array('jquery'), '1.3' );
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery.cycle');

     }

 }

 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'm_slider_add_scripts');


 function m_slider_cut_text($text, $chars, $points = "...") {

$content = $text;

$content = preg_replace('/\[.+\]/','', $content);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); 
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
$content = strip_tags($content);

$length = strlen($content);

if($length <= $chars) {

    return $content;

 } else {

    return mb_substr($content, 0, $chars)." ".$points;

}
}

add_action("admin_init", "m_slider_init");
add_action('save_post', 'm_slider_save');

function m_slider_init() {

    add_meta_box("feat_music", "Featured Music Options", "m_slider_meta", "post", "normal", "high");
    add_meta_box("feat_music", "Featured Music Options", "m_slider_meta", "page", "normal", "high");

}

function m_slider_meta() {

    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $feat_music = $custom["feat_music"][0];

?>

        <div class="inside">
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="feat_music">Feature in Featured Music?    </label></th>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="feat_music" value="1" <?php if($feat_music == 1) { echo "checked='checked'";} ?></td>

<th><label for="points">Artist/Song</label></th>
                <td><input type="text" name="artist_title" value="Artist - Song"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<?php

}

 function m_slider_save() {

    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
    return $post_id;
    global $post;

    if($post->post_type == "post" || $post->post_type == "page") {

            update_post_meta($post->ID, "feat_music", $_POST["feat_music"]);

    }

}

function m_slider_insert($atts, $content = null) {

    include (ABSPATH . '/wp-content/plugins/rated-featured-music/content-slider.php');

}

add_shortcode("featslider", "m_slider_insert");

$m_slider_img_width = get_option('img_width');

if(empty($m_slider_img_width)) {

    $m_slider_img_width = 320;

}

$m_slider_img_height = get_option('img_height');

if(empty($m_slider_img_height)) {

    $m_slider_img_height = 200;

}

if (function_exists('add_image_size')) {

add_image_size( 'feat_music', $m_slider_img_width, $m_slider_img_height, true );

}

function m_slider_get_thumb($position) {

$thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, $position);
$thumb = explode("\"", $thumb);
return $thumb[5];

}

//Check for Post Thumbnail Support

add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

function m_slider_get_dynamic_class() {

    $class = explode("http://", get_bloginfo("url"));
$class = explode(".", $class[1]);
    $class = $class[0];
    return $class . "_slider";

}

?>
```

**What is the callback code that I need to add to the Value Area?**

**The code below is the styling of the plugin and callback codes, what is the callback code to call back whatever is placed in the textarea.**

```
<?php

$m_slider_direct_path =  get_bloginfo('wpurl')."/wp-content/plugins/rated-featured-music";

$m_slider_class = m_slider_get_dynamic_class();

?>

<div id="featuredmusicbox">
<?php

    $m_slider_sort = get_option('sort'); if(empty($c_slider_sort))    {$c_slider_sort = "post_date";}
    $m_slider_order = get_option('order'); if(empty($c_slider_order)){$c_slider_order = "DESC";}
    $m_slider_post_limit = get_option('limit_posts');     if(empty($m_slider_limit_posts)){$m_slider_limit_posts = "-1";}

    global $wpdb;

    global $post;

    $args = array( 'meta_key' => 'feat_music', 'meta_value'=> '1', 'suppress_filters' => 0, 'post_type' => array('post', 'page'), 'orderby' => $m_slider_sort, 'order' => $m_slider_order, 'numberposts'=> $m_slider_post_limit);

    $myposts = get_posts( $args );

    foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);

        $m_slider_custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);

        $m_slider_thumb = m_slider_get_thumb("featmusic");

    ?>


            <div class="image"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('featmusic'); ?></a></div>
 <div id="titlelisten">
 <div class="titlefm"><center><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">TEXT AREA TEXT HERE</a></center></div> <div class="listenfm"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><img src="http://ratedrnb.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/listen.jpg"></a></div>
</div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your text is already in the array `$m_slider_custom`, from this line:

```
$m_slider_custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
```

If you just want the specific key `feat_music` you can use [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta):

```
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'feat_music', true );
```

Another, unrelated thing- I suggest spending some time with the Codex and cleaning up your URLs and paths. For example, this:

```
get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-admin/admin.php?page=rated-featured-music/options.php';
```

or this:

```
get_bloginfo('url') . '/wp-content/plugins/rated-featured-music/scripts/jquery.cycle.all.2.72.js'
```

or this:

```
include (ABSPATH . '/wp-content/plugins/rated-featured-music/content-slider.php');
```

.. will fail spectacularly under certain circumstances. WordPress has built in functions for getting any path or URL you'd need, see:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path

Comment: I don't get what you are saying lol or maybe you aren't understanding what I mean @Milo